# Where can I find correct source of Mantra Pushpanjali?

Tags: mantras, sanskrit

I'm concerned about [Mantrapushpanjali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantrapushpanjali)

The doubt is in this sentence:

> ॐ राजाधिराजाय प्रसह्यसाहिने नमो वयं वैश्रवणाय कुर्महे | स मे
> कामान्कामकामाय मह्यम् कामेश्वरो वैश्रवणो ददातु | कुबेराय वैश्रवणाय
> महाराजाय नमः || 2 ||

In the end, you see महाराजाय नमः

Now, I tried to find same on many other sources and all of them had same words, especially the *Namah*.

But doubt arose when I heard this on Star Plus Mahabharat. It is clearly heard them singing like "महाराजाय **विद्महे**" instead of "महाराजाय **नमः**"

I also noticed them pronouncing द**धा**तु instead of द**दा**तु.

So I'm not sure which one is correct and which one to trust.

**How do I determine which one is correct/pure or where can I find correct source of Mantra Pushpanjali?**

Note: If you want to hear it yourself, just type "Mahabharat Rajyabhishek Mantra" on YouTube and hear in the end, you'll understand my doubt.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Who wrote Rajyabhishek (coronation) song in Mahabharat?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/45024/who-wrote-rajyabhishek-coronation-song-in-mahabharat)

Comment: @Adiyarkku no. 1) It doesn't clarify those two words pronunciations. 2) IMHO It doesn't even answer what's asked in that particular question (who wrote it). He simply answered "nobody wrote it".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This shloka is from TAITTIRIYA ARANYAKA 1.31.6.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NaSjtamHFNk here you can hear the shloka from 1.11.46

https://vedicheritage.gov.in/aranyakas/taittiriya-aranyaka/# meanwhile this is from vedic portal by govt of india , you can hear from 1.01.27

so clearly pronunciation is महाराजाय नमः only and not दधातु but ददातु.

Comment: So the one we hear in Star Plus Mahabharat is incorrect? I can give you YouTube link if you could verify.

Comment: @Vikas yes please send , and please do mention at which time of video ,that shloka is being recited

Comment: Here it is. Only a short video. Once you listen all you'll notice those two words "Dadhatu" and "Namah" in the end: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ug_shltRm_0

Comment: @Vikas okay i will see

Comment: 1.01s and 1.10s (approx.)

Comment: And I find it hard to believe if it's a mistake by Star Plus.

Comment: @Vikas  regarding दधातु and ददातु  , I think due to so much background music and maybe due to voice of singer this confusion arose , and regarding महाराजाय नमः  , umm yes star plus is wrong . Mistakes happen I guess , no one is perfect .

Comment: Or maybe they deliberately changed last word to rhyme properly? But I doubt they should do like this.

Comment: @Vikas maybe yeah , they were singing in such a tone so they added a syllable I guess as without that syllable the shloka would have ended abruptly , but anyways I hope you got your answer :-)

Comment: Yeah we have to assume they deliberately did it.